# Calculate the orbit of a planet using matrices

Tags: c#, matrix

I'm am making a simulation of a solar system using C#. I'm using a scene graph. This way planets have parents which they then orbit. But I can't seem to get the math right. If I change the rotation speed of a parent(sun) then the children get effected(earth).

```
class Planet : Mesh
{
    private float a = 0;
    private float b = 0;
    const float PI = 3.1415926535f;         // PI
    private float dist = 0;
    private float rotaSpeed;
    private float orbitSpeed;
    private Matrix4 transform;
    private Matrix4 staticTransform;

    public Planet(Shader shader, float scale, float distance, float rspeed, float ospeed, String textureName) : base("../../assets/sphere.obj",shader, new Texture(textureName), Matrix4.CreateScale(scale))
    {
        dist = distance;
        rotaSpeed = rspeed;
        orbitSpeed = ospeed;
        staticTransform = Matrix4.CreateScale(1.0f);
    }

    public void setTransform(Matrix4 transform)
    {
        staticTransform = transform;
    }

    public override void Render(Matrix4 screenTransform, float frameDuration)
    {

        Matrix4 orbit = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(dist, 0, 0));
        Matrix4 circle = Matrix4.CreateRotationY(a);

        // update rotation
        a += rotaSpeed * frameDuration;
        if (a > 2 * PI) a -= 2 * PI;
        transform = circle * orbit;

        base.Render(transform * screenTransform, frameDuration);
```

Comment: What is wrong with the sun spinning at different rates affecting the other planets?  The sun spin at a constant rate which must be factored into the planets speed.  The sun speed is effecting the rotational acceleration.  the planets do not rotate at same speed as the sun due to frictional forces.

Comment: I didnt go into your code too much, but I would guess that the children get affected by the parent transform, yes? That would mean that when the parent rotates, the children get translated around the rotation origin. What you might waant to do, is have an empty object with the position of the star, then attach the star to it with its rotation and attach child bodies to that position transform as well and manage their position from there.